# Random letters returns blank

Tags: string, enums, elixir

I'm new to Elixir and trying to get a random letter from a function.

I'm tryng to define a function that return a random letter between a and z.

For for some reason this sometimes returns a blank character.
Why?

```
defp random_letter do
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  |> String.split("")
  |> Enum.random
end

def process do
  Enum.each(1..12, fn(number) ->
    IO.puts random_letter
  end)
end
```

Output:

```
g
m
s
v
r
o
m

x
e
j
w
```

Comment: As you're new, here's a tip: It would be a _lot_ more efficient to do this to get a random lowercase letter as a string: `<<?a - 1 + :random.uniform(26)>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "")
```

returns

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ""]
```

Look at the last element in the list and you get your answer :)

To avoid that, you can use `trim` option like this:

```
String.split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "", trim: true)
```

Comment: Thank you! Trim isn't default behaviour, that's weird.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to split the string, here are two alternatives. The second one is used when you have Unicode strings.

```
iex(1)> String.codepoints("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p",
 "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

iex(2)> String.graphemes("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p",
 "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

Or you can use

```
iex(1)> <<Enum.random(?a..?z)>>
"m"
```